# Service Worker not working in Offline mode with node js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, localhost, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

- I am trying to build a **PWA** with an offline first policy.

  - The server for the source files is a **NodeJS server**.
  - I am currently testing this on a **localhost** node server (not sure it has an impact ?).
  - Service worker + caching seems fine, but **in offline mode I only get the Chrome Offline Page**.

**Let's get into details :**

The page which is served (through the http://localhost:8080/place/test url)  has some client side JS, in which I register a Service Worker :

*client.js*

```
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker
                 .register(rootPath+'/js/service-worker.js')
                 .then(function() { console.log('Service Worker Registered'); });
    }
```

*service-worker.js* (based on the Google PWA tutorial)

```
var cacheName = 'myCacheVersion';
var filesToCache = [
    '../',
    '../place/test',
    '../js/client.js',
    '../js/service-worker.js',
    "../css/style.css"
];


self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
  console.log('[ServiceWorker] Install');
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
      console.log('[ServiceWorker] Caching app shell');
      return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(e) {
  console.log('[ServiceWorker] Activate');
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(function(keyList) {
      return Promise.all(keyList.map(function(key) {
        if (key !== cacheName) {
          console.log('[ServiceWorker] Removing old cache', key);
          return caches.delete(key);
        }
      }));
    })
  );
  return self.clients.claim();
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(e) {
  console.log('[ServiceWorker] Fetch', e.request.url);
  e.respondWith(
    caches.match(e.request).then(function(response) {
      return response || fetch(e.request);
    })
  );
});
```

In the Dev Tools Console, everything seems fine :

- The SW is registered
- The cache contains the elements I wanted to cache

But when I check the **Offline mode checkbox** and refresh my page url : http://localhost:8080/place/test , I only get the **Google Chrome Offline Web Page**.

**=> What am I missing there ?** (does it have to do with nodeJs ? with the localhost environment ? with my implementation ?)

I've been struggling with this one for a little while now...

I have checked in the "Application" tab and my service worker shows up as activated and is running.

*Note : If found a similar question here, but no satisfying answer over there : [Service worker not run in offline mode using nodejs server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43090875/service-worker-not-run-in-offline-mode-using-nodejs-server)*

Comment: You say the SW is registered; (as in a comment on the other question you link to) does it show up in the "Application" tab?

Comment: Yes, it show up as "activated and is running"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Fundamentally this is the same problem as answered here: [Service worker is caching files but fetch event is never fired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34147562/service-worker-is-caching-files-but-fetch-event-is-never-fired)

If you look in your console, you'll see that while the install, activate, caching, and registration all happen, the "fetch" won't. This is because you located the service worker under `js`, so for security reasons Chrome (etc) won't use it for any URLs except those in the same directory or below.

If you place your `client.js` and `service-worker.js` at the same level rather than in a `js` subdirectory, it will all start working. That will necessitate updating the contents of the files, which I will show below for reference.

One tiny caveat: I foolishly used IIS on a Windows box to work on this, and between that and Chrome they clung like grim death to the cached HTML files with outdated JS-file locations. I had to copy them into a subdirectory, making fresh URLs, to test the solution.

`index.html`:

```
<head>
<script src="client.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="cachetest.html">link to ct</a>
</body>
```

`cachetest.html`:

```
<head>
<script src="client.js"></script>
</head>
<body>cachetest</body>
```

`client.js`:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker
             .register('service-worker.js')
             .then(function() { console.log('Service Worker Registered'); });
}
```

`serviceworker.js`:

```
var cacheName = 'myCacheVersion';
var filesToCache = [
    '',
    'cachetest.html',
    'client.js',
    'service-worker.js',
//    "css/style.css"
];


self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
  console.log('[ServiceWorker] Install');
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
      console.log('[ServiceWorker] Caching app shell');
      return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(e) {
  console.log('[ServiceWorker] Activate');
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(function(keyList) {
      return Promise.all(keyList.map(function(key) {
        if (key !== cacheName) {
          console.log('[ServiceWorker] Removing old cache', key);
          return caches.delete(key);
        }
      }));
    })
  );
  return self.clients.claim();
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(e) {
  console.log('[ServiceWorker] Fetch', e.request.url);
  e.respondWith(
    caches.match(e.request).then(function(response) {
      return response || fetch(e.request);
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: You nailed it ! I just had to **move my service-worker.js to my root** and make a few changes to the file paths + cache file list paths to have is work... 
Note for later : keep in mind service-worker only has access to its level or below... Many thanks ! (I upvoted your answer, but being new here, it doesn't display yet...)

Comment: Thanks! Good luck with your other stuff. I'm going to see if this is also the answer to the other problem.

Comment: Or, you can! :-)

Comment: I also added my service worker to the root of my application <domain.com>/service-worker.js and things started working. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, placing registering sw and actual service worker fix the problem.